# Azure WebJob Console App connect to sftp site

Tags: c#, azure, ftp, sftp, azure-webjobs

I am a new to working with `Azure webjob` but I have come across an issue. I have a Console application written in C# in which I connect to an ftp site to download a file.

As so:

```
 using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
            {
                sftp.Connect();
                stream = new MemoryStream();
                sftp.DownloadFile(FileName, stream);
                sftp.Disconnect();
            }
```

When running this locally on visual studio it works fine, But once I build this and run it thru a scheduled `webjob` it fails to connect to the ftp site.

The logs output at this point is :

> "The connection was closed by the server: Failed authentication for virtual user: Username (ProtocolError)"

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: FTP and SFTP are two completelly different protocols. You are using SFTP, not FTP. Correct your question.

Comment: What SFTP library are you using? + Did you check SFTP server log file?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl  I'm using Renci.SshNet

Comment: Again, did you check the server log file? + Did you try to the same using a scriptable SFTP client? Like WinSCP? Would it be able to authenticate from the Azure scheduled webjob?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this `Failed authentication for virtual user` today at work.  In my instance I'm trying to connect to Bloomberg's SFTP server. My machine was trying to connect to the server from behind an IP not in the IP whitelist we provided Bloomberg.